# Sequence labeller

Tags: r, time-series, lapply

I am analysing a time series signal. I set a threshold to separate the noise from the baseline noise. In order to identify the properties of each signal sequence (duration, amplitude, maximum signal...), I built a function to aggregate all the signal points that are continuous as different "peaks". Despite this function does what I want, I was wondering if anyone can help me to make it more efficient -e. g. vectorization, because I aim to run the function on a data.table of more than 1M rows. Here is a sample data with the function:

```
# Generate dummy data
x <- sin(seq(from = 0, to = 20, length.out = 200)) + rnorm(200, 0,0.1)
x <- zoo(x)
plot(x)


# Label each point as signal (== )1) or noise (0)

y <- ifelse(x > 0.5, 1, 0)

# Function to label each peak

peak_labeler <- function(x) {

  tmp <- NULL

  for (i in seq_along(x)) {

    if (x[i] == 0) { tmp[i] <- 0 } # If baseline, mark as 0

    if (x[i] == 1) {

      # If x[n] belongs to a peak
      if (i == 1) {tmp[i] <- 1} # Label as 1 at t0

      else{

        if (!exists("Peak")) {Peak <- 0}

        if (x[i - 1] == 0) {
          # if previous point is no peak, add as peak

          Peak <- Peak + 1
          tmp[i] <- Peak
        }

        if (x[i - 1] == 1) {
          tmp[i] <- Peak
        }
      }
    }

  }

  return(tmp)

  rm(tmp, Peak, i) # Garbage collection
}

# Label peaks

dummy <- data.frame(t = 1:200, x,y,tmp = peak_labeler(y))

# Show data

ggplot(dummy, aes(x = t, y = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = as.factor(tmp), group = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`.

The test in the `cross_threshold` line works by evaluating whether y is on a different side of 0.5 than the prior y. If so, the sign of the two terms `y - threshold` and `lag(y) - threshold` will be different, leading to a TRUE, which is multiplied by 1 to become `1`. If they're on the same side of 0.5, you'll get a FALSE and a `0`. The `default = 0` part deals with the first line, where lag(y) is undefined. Then we add up how many cumulative crosses there have been to define the `tmp` group.

```
library(dplyr)

threshold = 0.5 
dummy <- data.frame(t = 1:200, x, y) %>%
mutate(cross_threshold = 1 * (sign(y - threshold) != sign(lag(y, default = 0) - threshold)),
     # Line above now optional, just if we want to label all crossings
     up = 1 * ((y > threshold) & (lag(y) < threshold)),
     tmp = if_else(y > threshold, cumsum(up), 0))

ggplot(dummy, aes(x = t, y = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = as.factor(tmp), group = 1)) +
  geom_point(data = filter(dummy, cross_threshold == 1), shape = 21, size = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: I have benchmarked this method an looks 100x faster. However, It classifies all the data points below the threshold as "Signal peaks". By that, I mean that in your figure you can see how the data below the signal is classified in groups 0, 3, 6 and 8. Thus, I would like to get rid of them and label them as 0 and the peaks should follow an n + 1 naming. Sorry if I made some impressions in my question.

Comment: Updated, I think should do that now.

Comment: Perfect solution!